# Error When Displaying Error Messages with Thymeleaf in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

When trying to display an Error Message I encounter a problem. I have 2 Thymeleaf templates so far, and on one where I add a new Employee if I violate constraint rules I get an error message like this:
[image]

This is the expected behaviour. I have written code so that if the user doesn't satisfy the constraint rules they stay on the same page and will need to make necessary corrections and submit the form again.

This is the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>New Employee</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h1>Add New Employee</h1>
    <br />
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/admin/save}" th:object="${employee}" method="post">

        <table border="0" cellpadding="10">

            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{username}" required/></td>
                <td th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('username')}" th:text="${err}" class="error"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" required/></td>
                <td th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('firstName')}" th:text="${err}" class="error" ></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" required/></td>
                <td th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('lastName')}" th:text="${err}" class="error"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" th:field="*{password}" required/></td>
                <td th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('password')}" th:text="${err}" class="error"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td><input type="email" th:field="*{email}" required/></td>
                <td th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('email')}" th:text="${err}" class="error"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Department:</td>
                <td>
                    <select th:field="*{department}" required>
                        <option th:value="${null}" th:text="'-----'"></option>
                        <option th:each="dept : ${departmentList}" th:value="${dept.id}" th:text="${dept.name}"></option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Role:</td>
                <td>
                    <select th:field="*{role}" required>
                        <option th:value="${null}" th:text="'-----'"></option>
                        <option th:each="r : ${roles}" th:value="${r}" th:text="${r}"></option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button type="submit">Save</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <div style="position:relative; right:108px; top:25px;">
            <a href="/admin/homepage">Go Back</a>
        </div>


    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
    @GetMapping("/save")
    public String showAddEmployeeForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
        model.addAttribute("departmentList", departmentService.getAllDepartments());
        model.addAttribute("roles", Role.values());
        return "employeeAddForm";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String addEmployee(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employee")Employee employee , BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){
        try {
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
                model.addAttribute("departmentList", departmentService.getAllDepartments());
                model.addAttribute("roles", Role.values());
                return "employeeAddForm";
            }
            employee.setDateEmployed(LocalDateTime.now());
            employee.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(employee.getPassword())); // triba mi DTO za ove stvari ?
            employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
            return "redirect:/admin/save";
        } catch (UsernameAlreadyExistsException ex) {
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", ex.getMessage());
            return "errorpage";
        }
    }
```

Now I tried to do the same with the other template but for some reason error messages aren't displaying BUT the constraint is respected so if for example username is too long it's not going to update and the user stays on the page but they don't know what's wrong.

This is the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Edit Employee</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h1>Edit Employee</h1>
    <br />
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/admin/update}" th:object="${employee}" method="post">

        <table border="0" cellpadding="10">

            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{username}"/></td>
                <td th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('username')}" th:text="${err}" class="error"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td><input type="email" th:field="*{email}"/></td>
                <td th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('email')}" th:text="${err}" class="error"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"/></td>
                <td th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('firstName')}" th:text="${err}" class="error"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}"/></td>
                <td th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('lastName')}" th:text="${err}" class="error"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>Department:</td>
                <td>
                    <select th:field="*{department}">
                        <option th:value="${null}" th:text="'-----'"></option>
                        <option th:each="dept : ${departmentList}" th:value="${dept.id}" th:text="${dept.name}"></option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Role:</td>
                <td>
                    <select th:field="*{role}">
                        <option th:value="${null}" th:text="'-----'"></option>
                        <option th:each="r : ${roles}" th:value="${r}" th:text="${r}"></option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>


            <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${employee.get().getId()}">

            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Edit"></td>
            </tr>


        </table>

        <div style="position:relative; right:108px; top:25px;">
            <a href="/admin/homepage">Go Back</a>
        </div>


    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
    @GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String showEditEmployeeForm(@PathVariable UUID id, Model model){

        Optional<Employee> employee = Optional.ofNullable(employeeService.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found")));

        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        model.addAttribute("departmentList", departmentService.getAllDepartments());
        model.addAttribute("roles", Role.values());

        return "employee-edit";
    }

    @PostMapping("/update")
    public String saveEditedEmployee(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){

        // skuzit zasto u onome gore employee-u poslanom nije moga vidit Id
        Optional<Employee> dbEmployee = Optional.ofNullable(employeeService.findById(employee.getId())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException("Employee not found")));

        // hidden mozda jebe, moram stavit od DbEMployee da bi radilo ioako imaju isti id
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("employee", dbEmployee);
            model.addAttribute("departmentList", departmentService.getAllDepartments());
            model.addAttribute("roles", Role.values());
            return "employee-edit";
        }

        employeeService.updateEmployee(dbEmployee, employee);
        return "redirect:/admin/homepage";

    }
```

I don't get any errors in the console so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I don't know if this is important, this is the code where I search employees by username and then display them and have an option to edit them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Find By Username</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div align="left">

        <h3>Find Employee By Username</h3>
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/admin/employee}" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="enter username..">
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

```
    @GetMapping("/employee")
    public String showFindEmployeeByUsernameForm(){
        return "employeeFindByUsername";
    }

    @PostMapping("/employee")
    public String showEmployee(@RequestParam("username") String username, Model model){

        Optional<Employee> employee = Optional.ofNullable(employeeService.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException("Employee with username " + username + " can't be found.")));

        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        return "displayEmployee";

    }
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Display Employee</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h2>Employee Data</h2>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Date Employed</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td th:text="${employee.get.getUsername()}"></td>
                <td th:text="${employee.get.getEmail()}"></td>
                <td th:text="${employee.get.getFirstName()}"></td>
                <td th:text="${employee.get.getLastName()}"></td>
                <td th:text="${employee.get.getRole()}"></td>
                <td th:text="${employee.get.getDepartment().getName()}"></td>
                <td th:text="${#temporals.format(employee.get.dateEmployed, 'dd-MMMM-yyyy')}"></td>
                <td><a th:href="@{/admin/edit/{id}(id=${employee.get.getId()})}">Edit</a></td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div style="position:relative; right:180px; top:27px;">
            <a href="/admin/employee">Find Another Employee</a>
        </div>

        <div style="position:relative; right:180px; top:27px;">
            <a href="/admin/homepage">Back To HomePage</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second form within the update method you are returning the dbEmployee instance retrieved from a database back and not the original Model object employee.  Unfortunately spring will remove the BindingResult (the errors) if a different instance of the model is returned back. This occurs in BindingAwareModelMap class in spring. Change your update method to

```
@PostMapping("/update")
    public String saveEditedEmployee(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){

        // skuzit zasto u onome gore employee-u poslanom nije moga vidit Id
        Optional<Employee> dbEmployee = Optional.ofNullable(employeeService.findById(employee.getId())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException("Employee not found")));

        // hidden mozda jebe, moram stavit od DbEMployee da bi radilo ioako imaju isti id
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
            model.addAttribute("departmentList", departmentService.getAllDepartments());
            model.addAttribute("roles", Role.values());
            return "employee-edit";
        }

        employeeService.updateEmployee(dbEmployee, employee);
        return "redirect:/admin/homepage";

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reponse. I'have fixed the problem there were two errors. First I did what you said and the second error is because of hidden input in template: <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${employee.get().getId()}"> When In showEditEmployeeForm method i sent an type Optional<Employee>

But when in saveEditedEmployee it seems that using @ModelAttribute converts it to Employee and then i have to change the hidden input to <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${employee.getId()}">so for that purpose i created one more template(employee-edit-fail.html) where it's written like so

Comment: Although sending dbEmployee  doesn't give any errors it just doesn't display the new(wrong) username but the right one(one from db which is already validated).
Hope I didn't complicate it to much in the comments and people hopefully understand.